# Other methods of getting a value from a form besides val()?

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a jQuery script that gets the "value" from an html form, but I also have a payment client that uses the same value.

#### jQuery

```
$('.calc').change(function(){
var valone = $('#os0').val();
var valtwo = $('#os1').val();
var valthree = $('#os2').val();
var total = ((valone * 1) * (valtwo * 1) * (valthree * 1));
```

#### HTML

```
 <select style="width: 190px;" class="calc"
 name="os0" id="os0" type="text">
 <option value="5">250 </option>
 <option value="6">500 </option>
 <option value="7">1000 </option>
 <option value="8">2000 </option>
 <option value="9">5000 </option>
 </select>
```

The issue is, these values need to be different, but in the same option.

So...
Is there a way to have jQuery retrieve a different variable from a form rather than just the "value" such as a label, name or ID to use in the jQuery equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So... Is there a way to have jQuery retrieve a different variable from a form rather than just the "value" such as a label, name or ID to use in the jQuery equation?

Yes.

Probably the best way (if you don't mind it won't validate in non HTML5 doctypes) is to use a [`data-whatever` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) (the `data-` prefix is important).

You can then access it with [`attr('data-whatever')`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or with [`data('data-whatever')`](http://api.jquery.com/data), but keep in mind the latter does some magic to attempt to return the type you want.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/5PFU7/).

Answer (score 0):

If you like to access the text inside the selected option(e.g. 250, 500 ) , you need to retrieve the text-property of the option:

```
$('.calc').change(function(){
  var valone    = Number($('#os0 option:selected').prop('text'));
  var valtwo    = Number($('#os1 option:selected').prop('text'));
  var valthree  = Number($('#os2 option:selected').prop('text'));
  var total = (valone * valtwo * valthree);
});
```